# How to "hack-drop" a database snapshot after SQL Server upgrade has botched it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm dealing with an [issue where database snapshots cannot be dropped after SQL Server has been upgraded to 2014](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/811464/existing-snapshots-can-not-be-accessed-or-deleted-after-sql-14-upgrade). The snapshots are defunct but cannot be dropped.

Now although the Connect item has a disappointing comment in it I assume that this will be fixed eventually. However, I need to deal with this soon.

Is there a way to drop a database snapshot that cannot be deleted due to this bug? I fear that I have exhausted all documented means to do this. It might take undocumented modifications to system tables. **Is there a way to force a database (snapshot) to be dropped?**

Comment: Have you tried shutting down the server and erasing the .SNP files for the snapshot?  (And do you have a test server to try this on?)

Comment: @RLF I did not try anything undocumented yet. I have a maintenance window every day so I can experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in an Azure VM, and resolve by simply setting the primary database offline and dropping the snapshot, eg

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 SET OFFLINE
DROP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012_SN001
```

Comment: That explains what happened to me a week ago. I was able to drop the snapshot and I didn't know why. I remember that I set the parent database offline.

Comment: Just an honourable mention for Azure VMs.  As a developer, I get £100 a month "free" allowance, so I created a SQL 2012 A2 VM from the gallery, took about 5 minutes to provision and connect.  I then downloaded the Adventureworks2012 sample db, attached it and created a snapshot.  I updated a few records to make sure the snapshot was doing some work, then upgraded to SQL 2014.  I shutdown the VM and took a snapshot with the Capture option, so I had a repeatable process.  I tried a few things, but the offline and delete worked a treat.  Now I can delete my VM.  Win for Azure!